# Write PSD matrix in terms of Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let  $A = \sum_{a\in[K]} w_ax_ax_a^T$, where $w_a \in\mathbb{R}$, $x_a\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $K> 1$. Is there a way to write
$$
A = \tilde{A_1}\otimes \tilde{A_2}
$$
for some matrix $\tilde{A_1},\tilde{A_2}$?

Note that $A$ can be rewritten as
$$
A = \sum_{a\in[K]} (\sqrt{w_a}x_a)\otimes (\sqrt{w_a}x_a)^\top,
$$

and hence the question can be reformulated as finding matrix $\tilde{A_1}$ and $\tilde{A_2}$ such that $A = \sum_{a \in[K]} A_a \otimes A_a^\top = \tilde{A_1} \otimes\tilde{A_2}$, for $A_a = \sqrt{w_a}x_a$.

Comment: The answer is no. **Every** PSD matrix $A$ can be expressed in the form of this summation for some choice of scalars $w_a$ and columns $x_a$.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my edit and see if you still think that it's not possible?

Comment: In your expression for $A$, $\otimes$ denotes the outer product, which in this context is distinct form the Kronecker product.

Comment: In other words, in your expression, $\otimes$ denotes the operation $v \otimes w = vw^T$. This is not equal to the Kronecker product $v \otimes w$, which is a column-vector.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll remove the edit.

Comment: what about $x_a \otimes x_a^T$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131031/discussion-between-apprentice-and-ben-grossmann).

Comment: Yes, it is true that $v \otimes w^T = vw^T$ when $v$ and $w$ are column vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. As a counterexample, take
$$
C = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad D = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}.
$$
Denote
$$
A = C \otimes I + I \otimes D = \pmatrix{2 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0& 1 & 1}.
$$
There are no matrices $A_1,A_2$ such that $A_1 \otimes A_2 = M$ except in the trivial cases where either $A_1$ or $A_2$ have size $1 \times 1$. It is easy to see that $A_1,A_2$ cannot both be of size $2\times 2$, otherwise, the upper-left and lower-right $2 \times 2$ blocks would need to be multiples of each other.

We can express $A$ in the summation form, however, with $K = 3$ and
$$
w_1 = 3/2, \quad w_2 = 1/2, \quad w_3 = 1,\\
x_1 = (1,1,0,0), \quad x_2 = (1,-1,0,0), \quad x_3 = (0,0,1,1).
$$

---

Note that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A_1 \otimes A_2) = \operatorname{rank}(A_1) \operatorname{rank}(A_2).
$$
If $A_1 \otimes A_2$ has size $4 \times 4$ and neither $A_1$ nor $A_2$ has size $4 \times 4$, then the ranks of $A_1,A_2$ must be either $1$ or $2$. Thus, it is impossible to have $\operatorname{rank}(A_1 \otimes A_2) = 3$. However, $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 3$.